# AWS SQS queue message count

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

Does AWS expose a API/method if  i can pull out number of message sent to SQS queue for a given time frame(for example a week).I am trying to build a tool to monitor cloud infra for an internal project in java.This is one of the requirement to display a graph with number of message pushed to SQS for a week. I also know we can check this in AWS console.

Answer (score 1):

You can retrieve queue metrics from Amazon CloudWatch. For example:

- `NumberOfMessagesSent`
- `NumberOfMessagesReceived`

See: [Amazon SQS Metrics and Dimensions - Amazon CloudWatch](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/sqs-metricscollected.html)